# Android caching like Trello app

Tags: android, caching, synchronization

When I create a ticket in a Trello board on Android app. Then I turn wifi on and the ticket syncs to web version immediately. Are there any tutorials for this offline caching and syncing technique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scheduled jobs to do this

Refer this [firebase-job-dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)